# how 3cxphone work without native sip stack on android

Tags: android, native, sip

I read some posts that said samsung galaxy s2 does not support native sip stack, but how does 3cxphone work in galaxy s2?

Is it depend on native sip stack or not, and how can I create an app for android similar to 3cxphone?

I tried to do one by SIP library in android sdk but it does not work on galaxy s2.

Maybe I misunderstood about what native sip stack IS?

Comment: I am also curious about this. Zoiper is also works on Samsung without sip library